# How can I create activation code for sign up process?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, user-profile

I'm sorry to take your precious time.
I don't know where to find answers for a react application using aws that I'm trying to build.
It's basically a simple profile app.
I just want to know what it's the best work around in order to achieve this process:

- give a custom code to a user
- allow user to register with aws by giving this custom code ( only if the code exist )
- bind this code to the user account in order for him to ad his informations
- allow a guest user to access profile info from url like " [https://www.profile.com/custome-code"](https://www.profile.com/custome-code%22%C2%A0)

If there is a better way without aws service feel free to tell me.
Either way if you have any answers for me, it would be awesome! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow. Plz post your question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Besides this show your code where you stuck. Its vague question. No one can help on these

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamVerma  and sorry about that, I'm not stuck with code but can figure it out how to build this process in my app, I understand that it's a vague question so I will try to build something and get back here. Thanks anyway